# Starting minikube in Ubuntu deletes local docker images

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

I have a dockerized application. When I am running it through docker-compose up, it runs fine and appears in `docker images`. But when I try to start a minikube cluster with `vm-driver=None`, then the cluster gives error and does not start. However, when I quit my docker application and start minikube cluster again, the cluster starts successfully. But then I couldnt find my docker application image I just ran. Instead I find images like below

```
k8s.gcr.io/coredns                         1.2.2               367cdc8433a4        5 weeks ago         39.2MB
k8s.gcr.io/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64      v1.10.0             0dab2435c100        5 weeks ago         122MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy-amd64                v1.10.0             bfc21aadc7d3        6 months ago        97MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager-amd64   v1.10.0             ad86dbed1555        6 months ago        148MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver-amd64            v1.10.0             af20925d51a3        6 months ago        225MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler-amd64            v1.10.0             704ba848e69a        6 months ago        50.4MB
```

Is this expected behavior? What is the reason if so?

minikube start --vm-driver=none

**Update**: I am working in an Ubuntu VM.

Comment: From where did you ran the command to list docker images? inside minikube? or from the host machine (I mean your ubuntu)? If you ran the command inside minikube, then its ok as expected. It seems you ran it inside minikube.

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie to Kubernetes. Not sure how to run a cmd inside minikube, I am simply running it from my Ubuntu console.

Comment: Please provide the error message. Assumption is that your running application prevents kubernetes from managing the images. (kubelet manages the docker daemon on nodes, afaik a mixed operation of manually controlled docker (images) and kubernetes is not part of the minikube design

Comment: So, to run command inside minikube, first run `$ minikube ssh`. Then you will be in the minikube shell. And then whatever you run command, actually will be executed in the minikube. Also you should know thar minikube creates a one node (master node named minikube) cluster, in which `kubelet` is the docker daemon. Actually its hard to say without knowing whats happening there. So provide details about what you did, what the output was, what you want specifically, etc. like these stuffs.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Minikube documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/572713c4819891c4b74483cfcb865f59bde74593/docs/vmdriver-none.md#can-the-none-driver-be-used-outside-of-a-vm):

> minikube was designed to run Kubernetes within a dedicated VM, and assumes that it has complete control over the machine it is executing on. With the none driver, minikube and Kubernetes run in an environment with very limited isolation, which could result in:
>
> - Decreased security
> - Decreased reliability
> - Data loss

Comment: Thanks for your reponse. I have updated in description that I am using an Ubuntu VM which is why I am using vm-driver-none.

Answer (score 0):

It is not expected behavior that `Minikube` will delete your docker images. I have tried to reproduce your issue. I had a few docker images on my Ubuntu VM.

```
$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY                                TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
nginx                                     latest              e445ab08b2be        13 days ago         126MB
busybox                                   latest              db8ee88ad75f        2 weeks ago         1.22MB
perl                                      latest              bbac4a88d400        3 weeks ago         889MB
alpine                                    latest              b7b28af77ffe        3 weeks ago         5.58MB
```

Later tried to run minikube.

```
$ sudo minikube start --vm-driver=none
  minikube v1.2.0 on linux (amd64)
  Tip: Use 'minikube start -p <name>' to create a new cluster, or 'minikube delete' to delete this one.
...
⌛  Verifying: apiserver proxy etcd scheduler controller dns
  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube"
```

I still have all docker images and minikube is working as expected.

```
$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-5c98db65d4-4vd2q           1/1     Running   8          21d
coredns-5c98db65d4-xjx22           1/1     Running   8          21d
etcd-minikube                      1/1     Running   5          21d
...
$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY                                TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
nginx                                     latest              e445ab08b2be        13 days ago         126MB
busybox                                   latest              db8ee88ad75f        2 weeks ago         1.22MB
perl                                      latest              bbac4a88d400        3 weeks ago         889MB
alpine                                    latest              b7b28af77ffe        3 weeks ago         5.58MB
```

After exit from minikube, I still had all docker images.

As you mentioned in original thread, you have used `minikube start --vm-driver=none`. If you will use minikube start without sudo you will receive error like:

```
$ minikube start --vm-driver=none
  minikube v1.2.0 on linux (amd64)
  Unable to load config: open /home/$user/.minikube/profiles/minikube/config.json: permission denied
```

or if want stop minikube without sudo:

```
$ minikube stop
  Unable to stop VM: open /home/$user/.minikube/machines/minikube/config.json: permission denied
  Sorry that minikube crashed. If this was unexpected, we would love to hear from you:
  https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new
```

Please try use **sudo** with minikube commands.
Let me know if that helped. If not please provide your error message.